# Unlink project as a maven dependency of another project in Spring Tool Suite

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, dependency-management, m2eclipse

I have some projects with many json files that when compiling them with maven generate many java bean classes and I have a main project that has the maven dependency of these other projects. Well, if the other projects are closed, when updating the maven dependencies it gets the compiled projects in my .m2 folder and the main project does not show errors in STS, but, instead, the projects are open, STS changes that dependency from the .m2 folder to the open project, and it does not find the java classes in the source folder because they are in the target.

How can I tell STS not to use the projects that are named the same as the maven dependencies? This way I compile the projects independently from the console and update the dependencies to the main project when necessary.

Comment: since this is more a general question around Maven projects in Eclipse, I added the m2e tag and removed the spring-tools-related one

Answer (score 1):

Right-click on the project, select "Maven" and then "Disable Workspace Resolution".  I do this for every project. I wish there was a way to set this as a global preference.  I wrote a shell script that whacks on all the .settings files in my project to set this flag for all my existing projects.

Comment: Thanks, it's works! The only downside is that now the code does not navigate when you click or control + click.

Comment: I have no idea what that means.

Comment: This solution is very good and achieves what I want, but it has the disadvantage that when I do control + click to navigate to the class it takes me to the package and not to the class of the other project, as it is logical.